# Get culture based on language

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get culture based on language  ?
For example if I will pass language = CHS it will retrieve  zh-CN based on National Language Support (NLS) API Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx

I belive .Net framework should provide us with method that support that .

your responce will be highly appreciated !

Comment: It seems you haven't appreciated other answers, since you've accepted only 10 of 29 questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will give you a list of matching cultures:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
.Where(c => c.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName == "CHS")
```

You may want to use `CultureTypes.SpecificCultures` instead of `CultureTypes.AllCultures`.